# Output of paste into Vim truncated

Tags: cut-copy-paste, putty

I am having issues with pasting text from the clipboard into Vim (v7.4) on an HPC cluster using Centos, which I have logged into using MTPuTTY. I still get the same error when I'm logging in via MobaXterm.

This is the result of pasting into e.g. sublime text:

[image]

Which is what's correctly on the clipboard.

However, when I try paste into Vim, using `shift+insert`, the output is truncated and contains some previous information  that I had on the clipboard (i.e. the `-Ou | \` part:

[image]

I have made sure I'm in insert mode. The issue seems to sporadically appear after using Vim for a while and the only thing that solves it is logging out of the HPC and logging back in again. I have absolutely no idea what's causing this.

I only have `:color desert` in my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Have you tried to use `p` (paste) instead of `shift + insert`?

Comment: You are probably pasting with vim in _normal_ mode (even though you mentioned that you made sure you're in insert mode). In normal mode, `p` pastes from the clipboard, `yth` yanks nothing, and `o...` opens a new line with the content that follows

Comment: @husB it is definitely always in insert mode. Unless there is a big and it says it's in isnert mode when it isn't.

Comment: I saw you bumping the question again with a bounty.. Since you mention pasting from the clipboard, instead of `shift+insert` in insert mode, you could also paste directly from the clipboard, natively in vim. In normal mode, what about `"+p` or `"*p`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
function! PasteFormat(x)
    let l=@+
    let l=len(split(l,"\n"))-1
    return a:x."V".string(l).'j='
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> ]p @+ =~ ".*\n$" ?  PasteFormat("p") : ((@+ =~ ".*\n.*$") ? PasteFormat("o<ESC>p"): "o<C-R>+<ESC>")
nnoremap <expr> ]P @+ =~ ".*\n$" ?  PasteFormat("P") : ((@+ =~ ".*\n.*$") ? PasteFormat("O<ESC>p"): "O<C-R>+<ESC>")
```

You may also might want to filter out more special chars that cause the cursor to move.

I haven't tested it (you may write this as text).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the command

```
:set paste
```

before pasting in insert mode?